# Автозаполнение поля адресс

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, vue.js

При нажатие на поиск по элементам, появляется подсказка с адресами, и перекрывает элементы для выбора. Как убрать эту подсказку ?
[image: Список закрыт подсказкой]
[image: Так должно выглядеть]

и

Код выше не помог, других решений я не нашёл.

```
<div class="form-group __pt0i">
    <select
        name="subject_id"
        class="chosen"
        data-placeholder="Регион"
        style="display: none"
    >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Адыгея Республика</option>
        <option value="2">Алтай Республика</option>
        <option value="3">Алтайский край</option>
    </select>
    <div
        class="chosen-container chosen-container-single"
        title=""
        style="width: 100%"
    >
        <a class="chosen-single chosen-default">
            <span data-chosen-icon="">Регион</span>
            <div><b></b></div>
        </a>
        <div class="chosen-drop">
            <div class="chosen-search">
                <input
                    class="chosen-search-input"
                    type="text"
                    autocomplete="off"
                />
            </div>
            <ul class="chosen-results">
                <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">
                    Адыгея Республика
                </li>
                <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">
                    Алтай Республика
                </li>
                <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">
                    Алтайский край
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="placeholder">Регион</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну а как вы открываете его?)) По вншнему пространству клик должен вызывать метод закрытия

Comment: С открытием и закрытыми проблем нет. Проблема в том что подсказки от браузера перекрывают список элементов для выбора.

Comment: Установка `<form autocomplete="off" ...>...</form>`  не помогает?

Comment: Попробуй не только инпуту, но и селекту тоже добавить атрибут отключения автокомплита (`<select ... autocomplete="off">`), т.к. вероятно что козлит тут именно селект.